# how to add sound to a game in qt in an interface

Tags: qt, audio, interface

i want to add a music in my game for a school project in qt but i saw that we have to use setMedia but he don't recognize it in the QMediaPLayer class and video about it are from so 2015 i think it change and i put a setSource but nos sound is coming from my game. I tried this but i don't have any ideas to make it work. Please help me.

```
#include <QMediaPlayer>

 QMediaPlayer * player = new QMediaPlayer();
    player->setSource(QUrl::fromLocalFile("C:/Users/Lea_CHABBAL/OneDrive/Bureau"));
    player->play();
```

Answer (score 1):

So that an audio file can be output, you must also set the output of your media player.
It is also important to make an entry in your project file:

`qmake` :
`QT += core gui multimedia` (add multimedia)

The code could then look like this:

```
#include <QMediaPlayer>
#include <QAudioOutput>

........
// if you want to use it as SLOT, it will be make sense to 
// declare the mediaplayer and output in a header file

QMediaPlayer *player = new QMediaPlayer;
QAudioOutput *output = new QAudioOutput;

player->setAudioOutput(output);
player->setSource(QUrl("path"));

output->setVolume(0.5); // <--- floating numbers. from 0 - 1

player->play();

........
```

Comment: They're is no error but when I launch it there is no sound so i don't know where to place it, i put it in the void of what make it launch but nothing. I also tried to put it before my void but nothing. I was thinking that my path is incorect so I put a file ressources with sounds.qrc so the path now is :  player->setSource(QUrl("qrc:/sound/printemps/La_musique.mp3")); is it correct ?

Comment: I think also that my computer doesn't see qt in output so it may be the problem but I don't know what to do

Comment: it also depends on which version you use. I'm currently using 6.4. maybe update qt if you haven't already. In the older versions of Qt this was directly via `QMediaPlayer` without `QAudioOut` (for output volume etc) . The resource also looks ok (hopefully it is also integrated with the resource editor).